# Replacing LXDE with XFCE, startx issues

Tags: linux, xfce, gui, desktop-environment, lxde

Apologies if this seems straight forward but I've recently downloaded XFCE to replace LXDE environment on my raspberry pi running raspbian.

I did this by using

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

and following all the instructions.

Then to remove LXDE I carried out:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove lxde
sudo apt-get clean
```

My problem lies that whenever I run

```
 startx
```

it still opens and runs LXDE?

I know that I should be running startxfce4 if I simply want to use XFCE, but I want to know how to completely remove LXDE?

Edit: Also how do I modify the startx file so that I can choose (if both are installed) which desktop environment I want startx to run (either lxde or xfce)?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the contents of your `$HOME/.xinitrc` file? Also the `startx` script just to make sure you're not calling `lxde` explicitly from there.

Comment: Re. completely removing `lxde`, on my system, Lubuntu 13.04, `apt-cache show lxde` tells me that it includes "lxde-core, lxappearance, lxinput, lxsession-edit, lxshortcut, gpicview, lxterminal, lxmusic, leafpad and xarchiver." Perhaps you could see if one of those is still hanging on. Again, on my system, `lxde` is just a _metapackage_ and removing a metapackage may not remove the packages it lists.

Comment: @vasa1 brilliant! that's solved it, I removed all the extra packages and it boots into xfce no problem now.

Comment: @terdon sorry for being a complete newbie with this, but I was trying to find the startx script for a while last night and kept going around in circles? How would I go about finding it?

Comment: Try `type startx`. But since this was solved, never mind. @vasa1 why don't you make that into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Raspbian, but on my system, Lubuntu 13.04, which is also Debian-based, `apt-cache show lxde` tells me that it includes "lxde-core, lxappearance, lxinput, lxsession-edit, lxshortcut, gpicview, lxterminal, lxmusic, leafpad and xarchiver." Perhaps you could see if one of those is still hanging on. Again, on my system, `lxde` is just a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) and removing a metapackage may not remove the packages it lists:

> So, when a metapackage is automatically removed by the removal or purging of any one, or more, of its underlying dependencies, all of the other packages that were in the metapackage's depends list are still installed on the system.

Source: the link given above